# Can I have two multithreaded functions running at the same time?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm very new to multi-threading. I have 2 functions in my python script. One function `enqueue_tasks` iterates through a large list of small items and performs a task on each item which involves appending an item to a list (lets call it `master_list`). This I already have multi-threaded using futures.

```
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(15) # Arbitrarily 15
futures = [executor.submit(enqueue_tasks, group) for group in grouper(key_list, 50)]
concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
```

I have another function `process_master` that iterates through the `master_list` above and checks the status of each item in the list, then does some operation.

Can I use the same method above to use multi-threading for `process_master`? Furthermore, can I have it running at the same time as `enqueue_tasks`? What are the implications of this? `process_master` is dependent on the list from `enqueue_tasks`, so will running them at the same time be a problem? Is there a way I can delay the second function a bit? (using `time.sleep` perhaps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't safe. If `enqueue_tasks` and `process_master` are running at the same time, you could potentially be adding items to `master_list` inside `enqueue_tasks` at the same time `process_master` is iterating over it. Changing the size of an iterable while you iterate over it causes undefined behavior in Python, and should always be avoided. You should use a `threading.Lock` to protect the code that adds items to `master_list`, as well as the code that iterates over `master_list`, to ensure they never run at the same time.

Better yet, use a [`Queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue) (`queue.Queue` in Python 3.x) instead of a `list`, which is a thread-safe data structure. Add items to the `Queue` in `enqueue_tasks`, and `get` items from the `Queue` in `process_master`. That way `process_master` can safely run a the same time as `enqueue_tasks`.

Comment: Ah Queue.Queue seems really nice -- I wouldn't have to implement any manual locking mechanisms if using it then? Also, if I am using two multi-threaded operations in one script, how should I go about choosing the number of threads? I chose 15 arbitrarily here, but if I have two processes running, should I do 7 for each? Is my logic flawed here?

Comment: @jeffrey Right, with `Queue.Queue` no locking is needed. The number of threads you should choose (and whether your should be using `ThreadPoolExecutor` or `ProcessPoolExecutor`) is dependent on what you're doing in `enqueue_tasks` and `process_master`. If you're doing CPU-bound work, you should be using `ProcessPoolExecutor`, `multiprocessing.Queue`, and `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` processes.

Comment: @jeffrey Because of the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), only one Python thread can actually execute at a time, so you don't get any performance benefit from multi-threading if you're doing CPU-bound tasks. Using multiple processes instead of threads works around the limiations of the GIL. The GIL can be released during blocking I/O, so threads are still useful for that.

Comment: I see, I'll have to experiment whether ThreadPoolExecutor or ProcessPoolExecutor is right for me then. But just to clarify, it is perfectly fine to have multiple functions using multi process and running at the same time provided I use a thread-safe data structure?

Comment: @jeffrey If you're using multiple processes, you need to use a **process-safe** data structure. So, [`multiprocessing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) instead of `Queue.Queue`.